# How to go back to the first line in a text file without reading it again?

Tags: java, io

I wrote this code and I think I went to the last line of the code while using line=input.nextLine(). Now I don't know how do I get back to the first line of the text file again. I am not allowed to read the file again.

```
        File file = new File(fileName);

        input = new Scanner(file);
        bufRdr  = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));


        this.cols=bufRdr.readLine().length();
        while (input.hasNext()){
            this.rows++;
            line=input.nextLine();
        }   
        theMaze=new char[this.rows][this.cols];
        int i=0;
        while(i<this.rows){
            line=input.nextLine();
            for (int j=0;j<this.cols;j++){
                theMaze[i][j]=line.charAt(j);
                }
            i++;

        }
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error......" +e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: This is a good example of a question that states the technique it is trying to use, instead of the real problem. It is better to ask about your real problem, but still mention the technique you are trying to use.

Comment: Why aren't you allowed to read the file again?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) and use [seek](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#seek%28long%29) to get to the top. BufferedReader reads sequentially; you cannot jump. You should check [mark](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#mark%28int%29) method of BufferedReader.

Comment: Can you explain this to me in detail. I have just started to use java and have not gone into a lot of depth.

Comment: @user30881 See this tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/randomaccessfile_readline.htm

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to. Instead of a 2-dimensional array of characters, you should use an `ArrayList` of `String`s. `ArrayList`s can grow on demand, so with them, you only need to read through the file once - you don't need to count the number of lines first:

```
ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
while (input.hasNext()) {
  lines.add(input.nextLine());
}
```

Comment: Is it something related to generics? If that is, I have never used that.

Comment: Well, ArrayLists are usually used using generics. But it's not actually compulsory to use generics with them. To make things easier for yourself initially, you can just leave out all the generic type parameters and it will still compile, with some warnings.

Comment: Can you show me how to do that? I am stuck with this coding for long time.

Comment: @user30881 I updated my answer with some code to show how it's done. You can omit the `<String>`s if you like.